# Trigger java function in azure container registry to output file content when file is uploaded in onedrive

Tags: java, spring, azure-container-registry, azure-triggers

When file is uploaded to onedrive I need to trigger java code to read content of the file. This java code is to be made as docker image and pushed to azure container registry. What steps should I take to pass this file as an input to java code and integrate these azure services together so that it can be read from inside docker container?

I tried using Azure functions that can trigger java code but unable to pass the file content to java code which has to be present in azure container registry.
I read about webhooks but webhooks needs URL to post the request. What URL should I used and how can I pass the file/file content in post request that I couldn't identify.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted an answer for the similar thread, please check and see if it helps.

Possible duplicate of [Trigger java code to download file from onedrive when file is uploaded to onedrive]

([Trigger java code to download file from onedrive when file is uploaded to onedrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55505659/trigger-java-code-to-download-file-from-onedrive-when-file-is-uploaded-to-onedri))

If you dont want to create logic app for the same its fine, you could have an implementation like below

```
using System;

public static void Run(string input, out string output, TraceWriter log)
{
    output = input;
}
```

Bindings

```
{
"bindings": [
    {
      "type": "apiHubFileTrigger",
      "name": "input",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input-cs/{name}",
      "connection": "dropbox_DROPBOX"
    },
    {
      "type": "apiHubFile",
      "name": "output",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "output-cs/{name}",
      "connection": "Onedrive_Connection"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Instead of posting answers to duplicates, please flag / vote to close as duplicate instead and keep your answers in one place.

Comment: Yes, that answer was posted by me only, but i believe we cant refer that answer to make it duplicate until it is accepted as an answer. Isn't it right?  As i tried from my side it didn't worked. Anyway Thanks for marking it duplicate.

Comment: No given that question was asked by the same person, you can always vote as duplicate. And if it was posted by a different user, then an upvoted **or** accepted answer is sufficient to be able to close as duplicate.

Comment: Cool. Will keep tab next time :)